# Azure ARM Template SQL Server Auto Tuning Deployment Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am deploying an ARM template with SQL Server Auto Tuning, I am enabling create index, drop index, and force last good plan . Here is my ARM template code.

```
 {
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "name": "[variables('databaseServerName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
  "location": "[variables('databaseServerLocation')]",
  "tags":{
    "displayName": "SqlServer" 
  },
  "properties": {
    "administratorLogin": "[variables('databaseAdminLogin')]",
    "administratorLoginPassword": "[variables('databaseAdminPassword')]",
    "version": "12.0"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "[variables('databaseName')]",
      "type": "databases",
      "location": "[variables('databaseServerLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Database"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('databaseServerName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "edition": "[parameters('databaseEdition')]",
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('databaseRequestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "firewallRules",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('databaseServerName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "[variables('databaseServerLocation')]",
      "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
      "properties": {
          "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
          "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "advisors",
      "name": "ForceLastGoodPlan",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "autoExecuteValue": "Enabled"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('databaseServerName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "advisors",
      "name": "CreateIndex",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "autoExecuteValue": "Enabled"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('databaseServerName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "advisors",
      "name": "DropIndex",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "autoExecuteValue": "Enabled"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('databaseServerName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

When I try to deploy the template I am experiencing this error. As far as I understand if I try to deploy twice in a short amount of time this error might occur. However, the first deploy was 24 hours ago.

```js
BadRequest {
  "code": "45363",
  "message": "Server automatic tuning settings from previous request have not propagated to all databases yet. Please try again in few minutes.",
  "target": null,
  "details": [{
    "code": "45363",
    "message": "Server automatic tuning settings from previous request have not propagated to all databases yet. Please try again in few minutes.",
    "target": null,
    "severity": "16"
  }],
  "innererror": []
}
```

Can anyone provide some insights into how I can avoid this error? When I try again in a few minutes it did work but it also caused an application to be down for a few minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{
  "type": "advisors",
  "name": "ForceLastGoodPlan",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "properties": {
    "autoExecuteValue": "Enabled"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('databaseServerName'))]",
    "CreateIndex"
  ]
},
{
  "type": "advisors",
  "name": "CreateIndex",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "properties": {
    "autoExecuteValue": "Enabled"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('databaseServerName'))]",
    "DropIndex"
  ]
},
{
  "type": "advisors",
  "name": "DropIndex",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "properties": {
    "autoExecuteValue": "Enabled"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('databaseServerName'))]",
    "[variables('databaseName')]"
  ]
}
```

I'd try and create a dependsOn chain with these sub resources.

Comment: Can you please explain the reason behind each chain?

Comment: order is more or less random, they just need to depend on one another, so they dont run in parallel

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly. The order will now be Database first => DropIndex => CreateIndex => ForceLastGoodPlan. I'll give it a go and let you know soon.

Comment: I still get this error regularly, every 5-6 deployments on the ARM template, and I have the same dependsOn on the advisors like above. Any ideas?

Comment: create a new question and link it here in the comments and I'll take a look.